# Byte to image conversion in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code which works fine in retrieving images, but sometimes it is not clear the image means previous image is loaded for all others, and if this happens, the proper image for a particular object does not get loaded.

The code in the handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string ID;

    if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        ID = Convert.ToString(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
    }

    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

    //context.Response.Buffer = false;
    Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(ID);

    //byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4095];
    int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    while ((byteSeq > 0))
    {
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
        //context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
        byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4095);
    }
    context.Response.Flush();
}

private Stream ShowEmpImage(string ID)
{
    DB_Connection();
    string sql = "SELECT Visitor_Image FROM Visitor_Master WHERE Visitor_Id = '" + ID + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    Object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    try
    {
        return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your initial paragraph is not clear.

Comment: A side note, there's no need to get put the `img` variable into a `MemoryStream`. Actually, your code has already consumed the memory of the full picture, so simply return the byte array and write the full array to the output